# iCloud storage reporting backups that do not exists

Tags: ios, icloud, backup

I disabled iCloud backups on all my devices, but the storage report still claims I have 2gb of backups stored. I've gone into the iCloud preferences and double checked that no backups exists. How can I remove free up the used space?

I should mention that my iPhone reports only 174.4KB of Documents & Data in "Manage Storage".

Comment: You may have documents stored in iCloud Drive. Check in iCloud settings on iPhone.

Comment: I meant add that in the question. I checked my settings (even opened the iCloud Drive app) and I have less than 200KB of documents stored.

Comment: You might have documents stored in iCloud (and not in iCloud Drive). Go to iCloud settings (in the settings app), choose storage (right under family), then Manage Storage, then look down. Often, apps like iMovie, Pages, and Notability just eat up data there.

Comment: @JohnRamos My iPhone reports only 174.4KB of documents & data under iCloud Settings.

Comment: Huh. next step: Check what's eating up your iCloud Storage by going to iCloud.com on a Mac or PC, then heading over to iCloud settings, then finding the bar that breaks down your storage categories. See an image here: http://imgur.com/lRE9MUr

Comment: Here's what iCloud.com shows http://i.imgur.com/TL4WoFs.png

Comment: Huh. Well, I think the next step is to determine what device the backups are on. Try both of the following: 1. On an iPhone/iPad go to Settings, iCloud, Storage, Manage Storage, and check which devices are using data (an old iPad or iPhone maybe, or even your current iPhone?); 2. Go to iCloud.com on a Mac, sign in, and go to iCloud Settings. Below that storage indicator, it should display devices with backups. Report back!

Comment: I called Apple Support, and they were not able to help. I spoke to a supervisor who said he "released" the 2GB storage, but it hasn't been reflected in my account after 24 hours. So, I dunno.

Comment: Do any of your other devices have backups? Are you sure that an old iPad isn't sneakily taking up storage data in iCloud?

Comment: And I assume you've checked the storage on iCloud.com (and not just in the Settings app)?

Comment: @JohnRamos Yes, I checked on iCloud.com. It is possible an old device's backup is taking up that space, but I no longer have that device in my possession. It was restored and given away.

Comment: This seems like a mistake/bug on Apple's end. Keep pestering Apple Support and/or wait for that data count to update. Or else keep bugging Apple until they give you free storage to compensate. If they can't resolve it, and you really need to get that data to go away, you might just want to delete/remake your iCloud account. If all else fails, switch to Android :). http://bit.ly/One-Plus-3

Comment: I have the very same problem.
Almost 3GB in "Backup" but with not backups there.
I have already deleted my iPhone backup, but that `yellow` backup bar is still there too…

Comment: @lucasarruda I had to call Apple 4x before I spoke to someone who could actually help me, and he had to refer my case to the Engineering department before it was finally resolved.

Comment: @RHPT thanks for replying.
I'll probably have to do the same!

Answer (score 3):

If you have two iOS devices, I would compare the Settings - iCloud - Storage - Manage Storage screens to ensure both agree. One device can get stale or cached data. If you don't have two, restart your device to check that it's updated.

If so, you will then want to go to iCloud.com on a computer and verify the number there. The web app allows you to clean or observe the rest of the backups. They are deleted photo albums (potentially) as well as backups of calendar, contacts, files and bookmarks.

IF at that point, you still think there's something missing - you'll want to escalate to Apple Support to http://apple.com/support/icloud

Answer (score 0):

My best suggestion is to check for apps like WhatsApp. It can backup data but will not show in iCloud. If that does not apply, I would call Apple Care and ask them to release the extra storage.